# WritableComparable object is not serializable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following classes for MR jobs but when i run the job the job is failing with the below exception kindly suggest.

```
    public class MongoKey implements WritableComparable<MongoKey> {
    ...
    private Text name;
private Text place;

public MongoKey() {

    this.name = new Text();
    this.place = new Text();

}

public MongoKey(Text name, Text place) {

    this.name = name;
    this.place = place;

}

public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {

    name.readFields(in);
    place.readFields(in);

}

public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

    name.write(out);
    place.write(out);

}
    public int compareTo(MongoKey o) {

            MongoKey other = (MongoKey)o;
            int cmp = name.compareTo(other.name);
            if(cmp != 0){
                return cmp;
            }

            return place.compareTo(other.place);
        }
    }

public class MongoValue implements Writable {
...
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {

        profession.readFields(in);
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

        profession.write(out);
    }
}

public class MongoReducer extends Reducer<MongoKey, MongoValue, MongoKey, BSONWritable> {

...
context.write(key, new BSONWritable(output)); // line 41
}

public class MongoHadoopJobRunner extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("usage: [input] [output]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        for (String arg : args)
            System.out.println(arg);
        GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);

        conf.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost/demo.logs_aggregate");

        MongoConfigUtil.setOutputURI(conf, "mongodb://localhost/demo.logs_aggregate");
        MongoConfigUtil.setOutputFormat(conf, MongoOutputFormat.class);

        final Job job = new Job(conf, "mongo_hadoop");
        job.setOutputFormatClass(MongoOutputFormat.class);
        // Job job = new Job();

        job.setJarByClass(MongoHadoopJobRunner.class);

        // job.setJobName("mongo_hadoop");
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        job.setMapperClass(MongoMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MongoReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(MongoKey.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(MongoValue.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(MongoKey.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(BSONWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(MongoInputFormat.class);
        for (String arg2 : parser.getRemainingArgs()) {
            System.out.println("remaining: " + arg2);
        }
        Path inPath = new Path(parser.getRemainingArgs()[0]);
        MongoInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inPath);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        for (String arg : pArgs) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
        GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, pArgs);
        for (String arg2 : parser.getRemainingArgs()) {
            System.out.println("ree" + arg2);
        }
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(conf, new MongoHadoopJobRunner(), parser
                .getRemainingArgs()));
    }

}
```

With the following exception

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.name.custom.MongoKey
...
...
at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.write(MongoRecordWriter.java:93)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
     at com.name.custom.MongoReducer.reduce(MongoReducer.java:41)
     at com.name.custom.MongoReducer.reduce(MongoReducer.java:11)
```

It seems there should not be any issue with the code but why its unable to serialize the fields i am totally clueless.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: How `MongoKey.write` is implemented?

Comment: updated the post for details, it is a simple Text instance being read and written

Comment: I think that `MongoRecordWriter` does not support arbitrary `WritableComparable` as key. See `write` method of `MongoRecordWriter` http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-hadoop-core/1.3.0/com/mongodb/hadoop/output/MongoRecordWriter.java#MongoRecordWriter.write%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29 .

Comment: I think line 78 talks about making things compatible, kindly correct me if my undertanding is incorrect.

Comment: can u share the complete `MongoKey` class codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see from `MongoRecordWriter` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-hadoop-core/1.3.0/com/mongodb/hadoop/mapred/output/MongoRecordWriter.java#MongoRecordWriter.write%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) it does not support arbitrary `WritableComparable` object as key. You can use one of these classes as key: `BSONWritable`, `BSONObject`, `Text`, `UTF8`, simple wrappers like `IntWritable`. Also i think you can use `Serializable` object as key. So i can suggest you two workarounds:

1. Make your `MongoKey` [serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) (`implements Serializable`, implement `writeObject`, `readObject` methods).
2. Use one of supported classes as key, for example you can use `Text` as key: `Text key = new Text(name.toString() + "\t" + place.toString());`

Comment: I think implementing Writable or WritableComparable makes it serializable so why do it again.

Comment: Implementing `Writable` makes the object serializable for hadoop framework, but the object is still not serializable in terms of Java. For example you can't write some `Writable` object to the `ObjectOutputStream` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.name.custom.MongoKey
```

exception is raised because MongoKey doesn't implement java.io.Serializable.

Add the Serializable to your class declaration